# how to show list, on option select in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have a list of products to show product details for me.

in my list, i have a select for my product model, i want to when i click one of the product model, in list show me products with selected model, how can i do this in laravel ?

my select is something like this :

```
<select class="col-7 border mt-2 pt-2">
      <option value="model1">model1</option>
      <option value="model2">model2</option>
      <option value="model3">model3</option>
      <option value="model4">model4</option>
</select>
```

this is my controller - index function for show list of products :

```
$forms = Form::latest()->paginate(15);
return view('Form1.list', compact('forms'));
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing, because i dont have idea for this and i dont know how to make this -.-